# email collection (from book), submit buttons collection

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with collection from symfony documentation. Here is my code:

controller:

```
$emails = array("first@qwe.com", "second@qwe.com", "third@qwe.com");
$myDForm = $this->createFormBuilder($emails)
    ->add('emails', 'collection', array('type' => 'email', 'options'  => array('required'  => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'email-box')),))
    ->GetForm(); 
$myDForm->handleRequest($request);
```

twig:

```
{{ form_start(myDForm) }}
{{ form_end(myDForm) }}
```

As you can see the code looks easy, there are no errors just an empty page... 
Could somebody point me where is the problem? I'm a beginner but it's almost exact as code in doc.

I'd like to make several submit buttons on a form this way but I stuck with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First:

Change

> GetForm

to

> getForm

```
$emails = array("first@qwe.com", "second@qwe.com", "third@qwe.com");

$myDForm = $this->createFormBuilder($emails)
                ->add(
                      'emails', 
                      'collection', 
                      array(
                          'type' => 'email', 
                          'options'  => array('required'  => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'email-box')),)
                )->getForm();
$myDForm->handleRequest($request);
```

I don't know what is your point to use emails with collection.

Second:

You are just opening your form. You are not giving any field to print.

```
{{ form_start(myDForm) }}
{{ form_row(form.emails) }}
{{ form_end(myDForm) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. Changing from Get to get didn't make any differece and adding form_row as well (doc: This helper also outputs form_rest() unless you set render_rest to false), but I tried this too. An e-mail collection is an example from the book, so I started with it.

Comment: You have to find what the problem is first. To do this: Make sure you are on dev mode (working with app_dev.php) Add these lines to see what is the problem: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Yes, I work on app_dev.php, as for the rest I need to figure out where to put those commands :) It may take a while.

Comment: Put in the controllers head that you set the form. Example: public function blablaAction(){ code goes here... Your rest of code }

Comment: I did that and it seems that there are no errors. It's strange for me that example code from the book  doesn't work..

Comment: It should be. Check the apache or nginx error logs. Blank white page is not normal.

Comment: Apache logs don't show anything special: error.log nothing but starting information and access.log only this: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2014:11:22:29 +0200] "GET /pierwsza/web/app_dev.php/do_zrobienia HTTP/1.1" 200 1509. I'm wondering if this is ok: "createFormBuilder($emails)"? Is this passing an array as parameter to collection?